# Deadlock when calling Dispatcher.Invoke() twice

Tags: c#, wpf, deadlock, invoke, dispatcher

I have two dispatcher:

```
dispatcher1
dispatcher2
```

Now, when I call (this is a simplified sample of my complex code):

```
            var ret = dispatcher1.Invoke(() => {
                return dispatcher2.Invoke(() => {
                    return new object();
                });
            });
```

I will run in a deadlock.

the call of

```
dispatcher1.Invoke()
```

is now waiting in

```
DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait()
```

and also the dispatcher2 after calling

```
dispatcher2.Invoke()
```

is waiting in

```
DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait
```

I cannot change the Invoke-Calls to async calls (BeginInvoke) because I need the result.

This was not the case with .NET 4.0 - only since I have changed to .NET 4.5.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Try calling `Invoke()` with `DispatcherPriority.Send`.  That should skip the dispatcher queue entirely.  Also, if `dispatcher1` and `dispatcher2` could be the same, use `CheckAccess()` to determine if whether you can just call the delegate directly.

Comment: This is not solving my Problem. When I use `DispatcherPriority.Send` it is doing the same.

Comment: The most obvious culprit would be a deadlock caused by a call into `dispatcher1.Invoke` while running on `dispatcher2`:  `dispatcher1.Invoke` blocks waiting on `dispatcher2.Invoke`, which executes code that attempts to call back into `dispatcher1.Invoke`.  Basically, making a blocking call into one dispatcher from another is begging for a deadlock.

Comment: Why do you have multiple dispatchers? There should be one UI thread only. More are almost always unnecessary and cause trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### This is a really, really terrible solution, and you should not use it.  Ever.

But if you feel like living dangerously, try replacing your `Invoke` calls with the `InvokeAndPump` extension method below.  (Don't replace *every* call to `Invoke` in your project--just the problematic ones in the question.)

```
public static class DispatcherExtensions
{
    public static T InvokeAndPump<T>(
        this Dispatcher dispatcher,
        Func<T> function,
        DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Normal)
    {
        if (dispatcher == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dispatcher");
        if (function == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("function");

        // If you've found this code in your project, you are doomed.  <3

        Action wait, notify;

        var currentDispatcher = Dispatcher.FromThread(Thread.CurrentThread);
        if (currentDispatcher != null)
        {
            var frame = new DispatcherFrame();

            wait = () => Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
            notify = () => frame.Continue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            var waitEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

            wait = waitEvent.Wait;
            notify = waitEvent.Set;
        }

        var error = default(Exception);
        var result = default(T);

        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            priority,
            new Action(
                () =>
                {
                    try { result = function(); }
                    catch (Exception e) { error = e; }
                    finally { notify(); }
                }));

        // Hold on to your butts...

        wait();

        if (error != null)
            throw new TargetInvocationException(error);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Seriously, though: heaven help anyone who uses this and expects it to work reliably.  I'm only posting it out of curiosity and because I am evil.  Mostly the evil.